# JWTRefreshTokenBundle returns suddenly 401 Bad credentials on refresh path

Tags: php, api, symfony, refresh-token, lexikjwtauthbundle

When I try to renew the token via <www.mywebsite.com>/api/token/refresh from my Symfony API, I get a 401 Invalid Credentials.
This behavior is suddenly appeared few days a ago in all the environments (local, test and prod) without any action from my part. The configuration was in place and functional for 3 years
Basically, the project is using php7.2, symfony4.4 and gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle V0.4.
Since the error is appearing in all environment, I was thinking that is could be related to the old version of the bundle. So, I upgrated it to V0.12 but no I don't notice any improvement.

```
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    path:     /api/token/refresh
    defaults: { _controller: gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken:refresh }
```

```
    firewalls:
        refresh:
            pattern:  ^/api/token/refresh
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: entity_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
               entry_point: App\Security\BasicAuthenticator
               authenticators:
                   - App\Security\BasicAuthenticator
                   - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Any help please? :)

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] It was an SSL issue between APIs.